# Help solving an ODE $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+y(x)=(\frac{dy}{dx})^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+y(x)=(\frac{dy}{dx})^2$

I made $u(y) = \frac{dy}{dx}$, so $u'(y) = u(y)\frac{du}{dy} \implies u(y)\frac{du}{dy} + y(x) = u^2(y)$ but here I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y''+y=(y')^2$$
Substitute $p=y'$
$$\frac {dp}{dx}+y=p^2$$
$$\frac {dp}{dy}\frac {dy}{dx}+y=p^2$$
$$pp'+y=p^2$$
$$\frac 12 (p^2)'+y=p^2$$
Substitute $v=p^2$ and solve.
$$v'-2v=-2y$$

Comment: How did you get $pp' = \frac 12 (p^2)'$?

Comment: Differentiate $p^2$ w.r.t $y$ what do you get ? @Mystery

Comment: @Mystery  $$(p^2)'=\frac {dp^2}{dy}=2p\frac {dp}{dy}=2pp'$$ $ \implies pp'=\frac 12 (p^2)'$

Comment: Yep, I'm just laughing because it was so simple and I didn't notice that. :p

Comment: lol no problem @Mystery you're welcome. You did a good job